# R help popping out to browser window

Tags: r, rstudio

In R Studio, all of a sudden (I probably update) when I use  to look up a function in the Console, the R help outsources to a my default browser, rather than using the RStudio IDE, which has a window for help files. Can somebody please help me to restore the IDE help functionality? I much preferred it when help popped up right next to the Console! R version 3.2.2 ("Fire Safety"), Mac OSX 10.11.2 ("El Capitan").

Comment: what is `getOption('browser')` for you? also your rstudio version would help

Comment: RStudio V. 0.98.1028. getOption('browser') yields: function (url) 
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url)
}
<environment: 0x7f982a838548>